# why template are defined in .h

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the-s)
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I'm not really understand why it's olbiged to define template implementation in a .h file?

Could someone give me a detail answer ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler needs the code to instantiate the template. If you put a template implementation into a .cpp file, you will be only able to instantiate the template in that .cpp file.