# Template Class Linked List Insertion Error

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

When I attempt to insert this 'food' object into my template class linked list 'test'. I get this error:

```
request for member ‘addNode’ in ‘test’, which is of non-class type ‘Catalog<FoodSource>()
```

Here's my coding, What am I doing wrong?

```
##main:##

int main(void)
{
    Catalog<FoodSource> test();
    FoodSource food();
    test.addNode(const &food);
    return(0);
}

##function definition in .h:##

template<class T>
class Catalog
{
    public:
        void addNode(const T& value);
};

 ##function implementation in .cpp:##

template <class T>
void Catalog<T>::addNode(const T& value)
{
    Node *temp;

    if(head == NULL)
        head = new Node (value, NULL);
    else
    {
        temp=head;

        while(temp->next !=NULL)
            temp=temp->next;

        temp->next = new Node (value, NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just found one of the many warts present in the C++ syntax. The standard requires that if an expression can be interpreted both as a declaration and as a definition then it must be considered as a declaration. For example your code

```
Catalog<FoodSource> test();
```

is not defining a variable named `test` but is instead declaring that there is a **function** named test that takes no arguments and that returns a `Catalog<FoodSource>` instance.

To define the variable you need to omit the parenthesis.

Note that there are cases where this trap is much harder to notice... for example:

```
double x = 3.14159;
int y(int(x));
```

as surprising it may seem in the above code `y` [is declared as a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)!

Comment: Thanks for the link. Effective STL is exactly where I learned about this hideous trap... and where I decided I'll never waste my time writing a C++ parser.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration and implementation of a class template should be [in the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the-s).

Also, you can just call `test.addNode(food);` in `main`.

Comment: The .h file is included in the .cpp. Calling test.addNode(food); gives me the same error.

Comment: @Michael: With templates this is not sufficient. The compiler needs the complete definition of the template when it is instantiated (in your case in `main`).

Answer (score 0):

Given definition for all the classes Node, FoodSource etc is available, you need to do at least the following:

1) Move the function definition to .h file

2) The first line in main function is ambigous. It should be rewritten as `Catalog<FoodSource> test;` because `Catalog<FoodSource> test()` will be treated as function prototype