# Why getting linker error with vector? 

Tags: c++, stl, linker-errors, std

I have for homework to write my own abstract class Vector. I make some of the code, but when I try to compile it I have error. This is the code:

***vector.hh***:

```
#ifndef VECTOR__HH__
#define VECTOR__HH_

template<class T> class Vector {
    int capacity_;
    int size_;
    T* buffer_;

    void ensure_capacity(unsigned size);

public:
    Vector(int capacity=10) 
      : capacity_(capacity), size_(0), buffer_(new T[capacity])
    { }

    ~Vector() {
        delete []buffer_;
    }

    int size() const {
        return size_;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return size_ == 0;
    }

    T& operator[](int n) {
        return buffer_[n];
    }

    const T& operator[](int n) const {
        return buffer_[n];
    }

    void clear() {
        // TODO
    }

    int capacity() const {
        return capacity_;
    }

    T& front() {
        return buffer_[0];
    }

    const T& front() const {
        return buffer_[0];
    }

    T& back() {
        return buffer_[size_-1];
    }

    const T& back() const {
        return buffer_[size_-1];
    }

    void push_back(const T& value);
};
#endif
```

***vector.cc***:

```
#include "vector.hh"

template<class T> 
void Vector<T>::ensure_capacity(unsigned size) {
    if(capacity_>size+1) {
        return;
    } 

    capacity_ = capacity_ ==0?1:capacity_;

    while(capacity_<size+1) {
        capacity_*=2;
    }

    T* old_buffer = buffer_;
    buffer_ = new T[capacity_];
    memcpy(buffer_, old_buffer, sizeof(T)*size_);

    delete [] old_buffer;
}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(const T& value) {
    ensure_capacity(size()+1);

    buffer_[size_] = value;
    size_++;
    buffer_[size_] = '/0';
}
```

***main.cc***:

```
#include "vector.hh"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Vector<int> v(2);
    v.push_back(10);

    cout << v[0];

    return 0;
}
```

And error is:

> g++ -c -o main.o main.cc
>   
> g++ -Wall -g vector.o main.o -o hw02vector
>   
> main.o: In function `'main'`:
>   
> main.cc:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `'Vector<int>::push_back(int const&)'`
>   
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   
> make: *** [hw02vector] Error 1

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/) might help.

Comment: +1 for actually making the effort and asking a question when stuck rather than simply asking for teh codez! :)

Comment: note that double-underscore is reserved for library implementors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linker error is coming because, for `template` classes the definition should **always be visible**. Either you can move all the content of `vector.cc` into `vector.h`. Or you can simply include `vector.cc` wherever you include `vector.h`.

**side note**:

Following lines in your .h file doesn't help:

```
#ifndef VECTOR__HH__
#define VECTOR__HH_
```

make both the macros similar such as, `VECTOR__HH`. This macros are used to avoid multiple inclusion of files.

Answer (score 5):

In template programmming, the  *definition* of the functions should be visible where the class template is defined. That is usually done by defining the functions inside the class itself.

So there are two ways you can solve your problem:

- Move all the definitions from `vector.cpp` to `vector.hh` (which is in fact the usual solution). And delete `Vector.cpp` as its not needed.
- Or, include the `vector.cpp` file at the end of `vector.hh` file, after the definition of `Vector` class template, like this:

  ```
  #ifndef VECTOR__HH__
  #define VECTOR__HH__  //<--- corrected this also!

  template<class T> 
  class Vector {
     //...
  };

  //...

  #include "vector.cpp"

  #endif VECTOR__HH__
  ```

Comment: there is a mistake made in `#define` also in the question, you can correct it in your code.