# Template definition?

Tags: c++, templates, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)
>   [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the)

I have two basic questions about function templates in c++.

1. Is it necessary to define template in .h file?
2. I have created a dll and exported a whole c++ class in that dll. And this class contains a function template. I am calling this template inside a another module that lodes this dll. So when this template related object file will be created.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Almost always. Tons of dups of this part of the question.
2. The app that's loading the DLL should have already pulled in the template (see #1) so loading at runtime is irrelevant. Also note that C++ ABI is quite finicky and putting a public C++ API into a DLL is asking for all sorts of subtle ABI breakage.