# Inheritance and conversion between 2 classes failed c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, implicit-conversion, radix, derived-class

I have class Signal and Image and both classes have method with same name but different input parameters and output parameter. Is is allowed?

```
template <class T> class Signal {
public:
    Signal<T> zeroPadding(Signal<T>);
}

template <class T> class Image:public Signal<T>
{
public:
    Image(void);
    ~Image(void);
    Image(int,int);
    Image(int,int,double);
    Image(int,int,double,double);
    Signal<T> zeroPadding(Image<T>);

    template <class T> Image<T>::Image(int width,int height):Signal(width,height) {}

    template <class T> Image<T>::Image(int width,int height,double dt):Signal(width,height,dt) {}

    template <class T> Image<T>::Image(int width,int height,double dt,double t0 ):Signal(width,height,dt,t0) {}


    template <class T> Signal<T> Image<T>::zeroPadding(Image<T> im2){
         Image<T> i1 =(*this);
         Image<T> i2 =im2;

         if (i1.getHeight()==i2.getHeight()){
          ....
          return(im2);
         }
    }    
}   

int main() {

    Image<int> *a=new Image<int>(2,3);
    Image<int> *b=new Image<int>(1,3);
    (*a).zeroPadding(*b); //when I try to debug it failed with error error LNK2019:
                          //unresolved external symbol 
                          //"public: __thiscall Signal<int>::~Signal<int>(void)" (??1?$Signal@H@@QAE@XZ)
                          //referenced in function 
                          //"public: __thiscall Image<int>::~Image<int>(void)" (??1?$Image@H@@QAE@XZ)
}
```

Another question: What about if I want to call in main function (*a).Signal::zeroPadding(*b) how I can convert (*a) and (*b) to be Signal?

Comment: Please implement Signal<T> zeroPadding(Signal<T>)

Comment: You've posted this code yesterday already. It's still syntacticaly broken.

Comment: A minus one for posting again (assuming @jrok is right)

Comment: I implemented zeroPadding in class Signal and my class Signal is not in the same file with class Image but I put here all together so you can see declaration in both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how the linker works with templates, your implementation should be on the same file as the declaration. You get LNK2019 because the method is only *declared* but not *defined*, the compiler doesn't know what to do with it.

Conversion is possible. You need to explicitly cast a pointer to a or b as Signal.

Comment: I implemented method zeroPadding in class Signal and implementation is in the same file as the declaration but I didn't put here just to show both classes but I still have the same error.

Comment: If I add line in main function like example Signal<int> *pB = static_cast<Signal<int>*>(a);   or something like this   Signal<int> *pb=a; I still get error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is allowed. If member functions are not declared as virtual, then the functions to be called are determined by the caller's class. In your case, The `zeroPadding` function is being called by Image type which is the derivative class, so the functions in the Image class will overload the base class.

And your error message

```
unresolved external symbol 
public: __thiscall Signal<int>::~Signal<int>(void)" (??1?$Signal@H@@QAE@XZ)referenced in function 
public: __thiscall Image<int>::~Image<int>(void)" (??1?$Image@H@@QAE@XZ)
```

implies that you have declared the destructor for `Signal` and `Image` template class, but didn't implement them, so there will be a link error;

And for your last question, since *a and *b are the derivative class instances of class `Signal`, so you can convert them to Signal at ease. Every simple methods of type casting will do that.`static_cast<Signal<int> >(*a)` or directly use `(Signal)(*a)` is enough.

**Update**: Seems like that this is a very old but common met issue about **seperate compilation**. :)

What is *seperate compilation*? An easy way to explain, if you put your implementation codes in a different source file with the declaration file in writing a template class, then you are using seperate compilation. There is a keyword `export` specifically for  this scenario, but the compiler support isn't that good.

Suggestion is that to put the implementation codes together into the declaration file or maybe include the implementation file into the header file for *template class*.

[Templates and separate compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191210/templates-and-separate-compilation)

http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~bi/se516/chapter4/tsld022.htm

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/73735/

Comment: When I create classes I got constructor and destructor for both classes Signal(void), ~Signal(void), Image(void), ~Image(void) and in Image.cpp and Signal.cpp I got their implementation; for example for constructor of class Image in Image.cpp I got            template <class T> Image<T>::Image(void)
{
}

Comment: Do I have to implement something additional?

Comment: You used seperate compilation?

Comment: Conversion like this works Signal<int> *pB=static_cast<Signal<int> *>(a); Signal<int> *pB1=static_cast<Signal<int> *>(b); so now if I want to call something like this (*pB).zeroPadding(*pB1); I got same error

Comment: @user3094708 , it's not about the types. Try google `seperate compilation`. Put your implementation codes into your header file, that should solve your problem.

Comment: @ richard.g You were right when I put declarations in Signal.h  and Image.h and implementation in Signal.cpp and Image.cpp it breaks because of template classes. But when I put everything in Signal.h  and Image.h it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3094708 ;} I am glad that I can help. Please consider accepting my answer. It will win you a `scholar` badge!