# c++ undefined reference to constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++14

I am  making a class for graph, maybe i am not doing it the best way but the idea was to start for somewhere. 
I have this class graph.h

```
template <class T>
struct node
{
    int index;
    T name;
    vector<int> neighbours;
};

struct lengths{
    int node_1;
    int node_2;
    int length;
};

template <class T>
class graph : public vector<node<T>>
{
     public:
        graph();

     ...
}
```

and graph.cpp

```
template <class T>
graph<T>::graph(){
    directed = false;     //flag for dir graph, default false
    nodes = 0;               //number of nodes in the graph

}
```

and in main i have

```
graph<int> g;
```

but when i try to build it i get error

```
main.cpp undefined reference to `graph<char>::graph()'
```

I use GNU GCC Compiler [-std=c++14]

Comment: Dont implement templates in a seperate cpp.

Comment: in your header did you include the templated implementation/cpp file?

Comment: Duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191210/templates-and-separate-compilation

Comment: Think about it. How can `graph<T>::graph()` be compiled in isolation. The type is not known so there is nothing to compile. The error should be clearer, with vs14 `unrecognizable template declaration/definition`