# Linker error with Boost Serialization using a particular class in a test executable, but not in production executable

Tags: boost, opencv, cmake, ld, boost-serialization

I'm using Boost 1.49, OpenCV 2.3.1, CMake 2.8 in a C++ project.

I'm building two executables with the same header file, one for production and the other for testing. The `contest.hpp` file specifies:

```
namespace boost
{
   namespace serialization 
   {

   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive& ar, cv::Point& p, const unsigned int version);

   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive& ar, cv::Rect_<int>& r, const unsigned int version);

   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive& ar, cv::Size_<int>& s, const unsigned int version);
   }
}
```

and these are implemented in `contest.cpp` file like

```
namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, cv::Point& p, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & p.x;
        ar & p.y;
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, cv::Rect_<int>& r, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & r.x;
        ar & r.y;
        ar & r.height;
        ar & r.width;
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, cv::Size_<int>& s, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & s.width;
        ar & s.height;
    }

    }
}
```

And `test-contest.cpp` mundanely tests these like

```
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Serialization1)
{

Point point_write(3, 5);
{
    ofstream point_file("Point.txt");
    ar::text_oarchive point_archive(point_file);
    sr::serialize(point_archive, point_write, 0);
}
Point point_read(0, 0);
{
    ifstream point_file("Point.txt");
    ar::text_iarchive point_archive(point_file);
    sr::serialize(point_archive, point_read, 0);
}
BOOST_CHECK(point_read == point_write);


Rect rect_write(3, 5, 1, 7);
{
    ofstream rect_file("Rect.txt");
    ar::text_oarchive rect_archive(rect_file);
    sr::serialize(rect_archive, rect_write, 0);
}
Rect rect_read(0, 0, 0, 0);
{
    ifstream rect_file("Rect.txt");
    ar::text_iarchive rect_archive(rect_file);
    sr::serialize(rect_archive, rect_read, 0);
}
BOOST_CHECK((rect_read.x) == (rect_write.y) && (rect_read.y) == (rect_write.y));

Size size_write(3, 5);
{
    ofstream size_file("Size.txt");
    ar::text_oarchive size_archive(size_file);
    sr::serialize(size_archive, size_write, 0);
}
Size size_read(0, 0);
{
    ifstream size_file("Size.txt");
    ar::text_iarchive size_archive(size_file);
    sr::serialize(size_archive, size_read, 0);
}
BOOST_CHECK(size_read == size_write);
}
```

where `sr` and `ar` are defined in `common.hpp` like

```
namespace ar = ::boost::archive;
namespace sr = ::boost::serialization;
```

The makefiles are produced from CMake configuration like:

```
link_directories(${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/libboost/lib)
link_directories(${DEPENDENCY_DIR}/libopencv/lib)

add_executable(test-contest test-contest.cpp contest.cpp)
add_executable(contest main.cpp contest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test-contest boost_serialization opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc boost_program_options boost_unit_test_framework boost_filesystem)

target_link_libraries(contest boost_serialization opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc boost_program_options boost_filesystem)
```

so, the *moral* of the story is, both `contest` and `test-contest` are compiled and linked against the same **header** and **libraries**. Note that other Boost libraries are linked and tested successfully.

When it comes to `make` after `cmake 'Unix Makefiles' ..`, for `contest` it says

```
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/contest.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/contest.dir/contest.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable contest
[ 60%] Built target contest
```

but for `test-contest`

```
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test-contest.dir/test-contest.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test-contest.dir/contest.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable test-contest
CMakeFiles/test-contest.dir/test-contest.cpp.o: In function `otap::TPageImage::Serialization1::test_method()':
/home/iesahin/Repository/otapexplorer/cli/contest-2012/test-contest.cpp:119: undefined reference to `void boost::serialization::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, cv::Rect_<int>&, unsigned int)'
/home/iesahin/Repository/otapexplorer/cli/contest-2012/test-contest.cpp:125: undefined reference to `void boost::serialization::serialize<boost::archive::text_iarchive>(boost::archive::text_iarchive&, cv::Rect_<int>&, unsigned int)'
/home/iesahin/Repository/otapexplorer/cli/contest-2012/test-contest.cpp:133: undefined reference to `void boost::serialization::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, cv::Size_<int>&, unsigned int)'
/home/iesahin/Repository/otapexplorer/cli/contest-2012/test-contest.cpp:139: undefined reference to `void boost::serialization::serialize<boost::archive::text_iarchive>(boost::archive::text_iarchive&, cv::Size_<int>&, unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test-contest] Error 1
```

And IMHO the weirdest part is, there are no errors for `serialize(Archive, cv::Point, int)` which is from the same header/library in OpenCV with `serialize(Archive, cv::Rect_<int>, int)` or `cv::Size_<int>`. Their serialization/test functions are almost identically defined.

I'm linking these `serialize` functions from `contest.cpp` file successfully. I tried replacing `Rect` with `Rect_<int>` in the definitions, to no change. I tried changing the order of libraries in `CMakeLists.txt` and took `boost_serialization` from the end to its current place, to no avail.

Where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the implementations of your three `serialize` functions moved from `contest.cpp` to `contest.hpp`.

For the reasons why, see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) or [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I'm still wondering why it was linking one function and not the next.