# gcc linking error on template method

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors

I hit this linker error and am having a little trouble getting past it.

> `o/foo/bar.cc.o: In function 'foo::bar()':
>   bar.cc:(.text+0x728): undefined reference to 'rf<PlayerInfo> Util::getClosestToGlobal<PlayerInfo>(std::vector<rf<bats::PlayerInfo>, std::allocator<rf<PlayerInfo> > >, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1>)'`

`Util.h` file defines:

```
template <class ObjectClass>
static rf<ObjectClass> getClosestToGlobal(
    std::vector<rf<ObjectClass> > objects, Eigen::Vector3d targetPosGlobal);
```

`Util.cpp` defines:

```
template <class ObjectClass>
rf<ObjectClass> Util::getClosestToGlobal(
    std::vector<rf<ObjectClass> > objects, Eigen::Vector3d targetPosGlobal)
{
    // ...
}
```

I know that my cpp file compiled successfully as it recreates the .o file as expected.

Have I provided enough information here for someone more experienced to identify the problem? If not, where else should I be looking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the)

Comment: @Bo, it may be a duplicate, though at the time I asked I had no idea what the problem was :)  Thanks for the link.  It's also pretty similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your templated function in the header file in which it was declared.

Comment: Is that always the case for templated functions?

Comment: AFAIK. C++11 added `extern templates` for this purpose, but I think they've been since removed.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  It seems that you can define template methods in cpp files if you know the template types ahead of time.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file

Answer (score 2):

Template class/method definitions should be available [in the header file](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13).

Comment: The information you linked to semi-contradicts the 'must' in your statement though, assuming you know the types that will be used in the template at compile time (which I do in this case.)  Useful information, thanks.  I'm enjoying learning C++.

Comment: That is not a common situation. I'll modify the "must" anyway, but the correct way to define templates is to define them in the header file, or to create another type of file(sometimes a ".ipp") which will be included at the end of your header. That is just a workaround.