# C++ -- Can I use a template function that is not implemented in a header file?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)
>   [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the)

I have three files. In one, base.h, I have a class that has a member utilizing a template:

```
class Base {
    protected:
        template <class T>
            void doStuff(T a, int b);
};
```

In base.cpp, I implement Base::doStuff():

```
#include "base.h"

template <class T>
void Base::doStuff(T a, int b) {
    a = b;
}
```

I then try to use this in another class in my project:

```
#include "base.h"

void Derived::doOtherStuff() {
    int c;
    doStuff(3, c);
}
```

But I get a linking error that states that it can't find 'doStuff(int, int)'

From what I've seen, this is not possible in C++03 without moving the implementation of this function into the header file. Is there a clean way to do this? (I'm fine with using C++11x features).

Comment: A template is exactly that what its named: a template for a function. Therefor `doStuff<int>` is something different than `doStuff<char>`. It will generate 2 functions one for `int` types and one for `char` types. Since its not a function you cant prototype it. This is the simple answere.

Comment: You can add `template void Base::doStuff<int> (int a, int b);` to your `.cpp` file to explicitly instantiate the template for an `int` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Its a common idiom to place template definitions into an `.inl` file along with inline function definitions, and include it at the end of `.h` file:

base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

class Base {
    protected:
        template <typename T>
        void doStuff(T a, int b);
};

#include "base.inl"

#endif
```

base.inl

```
template <typename T>
void Base::doStuff(T a, int b) {
    a = b;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I do that unless I somehow get a better response.

Comment: this does not solve an issue where the implementation uses some dependant header. export templates was part of standard and had implementations. hoping to see it next standard after 20