# Define template specialization in cpp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, template-specialization

I can define a specialized function in a cpp like so...

// header

```
template<typename T>
void func(T){}

template<>
void func<int>(int);
```

// cpp

```
template<>
void func<int>(int)
{}
```

How can I define a method in a specialized class in a cpp? Like so (which doesn't work, I get `error C2910: 'A<int>::func' : cannot be explicitly specialized`)...

// header

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    static void func(T){}
};

template<>
struct A<int>
{
    static void func(int);
};
```

// cpp

```
template<>
void A<int>::func(int)
{}
```

Comment: Did you check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file

Comment: @Pukku That concerns specialization of a method in a non-templated class, which is actually the same as specialization of a standalone function (as in my working example above). I'm asking about defining a method in a specialized _class_ in a cpp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use following syntax in your `.cpp` file:

```
void A<int>::func(int)
{
}
```

This is Visual C++ kinda feature.

See [MSDN C2910 error description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx7k7hcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details:

> This error will also be generated as a result of compiler conformance work that was done in Visual Studio .NET 2003:. For code will be valid in the Visual Studio .NET 2003 and Visual Studio .NET versions of Visual C++, **remove template <>**.

Comment: This is a compiler dependent feature of Visual Studio.  See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file