# Template specialization implementation in cpp file causes template-id does not match error

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, virtual

Consider the following code:

```
class Bar;

enum Values
{
  ValA,
  ValB, // ...
};

template< typename T >
struct Foo : virtual public Bar
{
};

template<>
struct Foo< ValA >
{
  void doSomething();
};
```

If I define the implementation of `doSomething()` in the header file, the program doesn't complain when I use `Foo::doSomething()`. However, if I move the implementation to a cpp file, as follows, I get an error:

```
template<>
void Foo< ValA >::doSomething()
{
  // ...
}
```

The error:

```
error: template-id 'doSomething<>' for 'void Foo<(Values)0u>::doSomething()' does not match any template declaration.
```

I'm not sure why this is failing. Moving the specialized implementation to a cpp file should not be a problem, I believe. I've done this before.

Comment: Take a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034799/define-template-specialization-in-cpp?rq=1

Comment: `Foo< ValA >` is not a template. It's (just) a class. Drop the `template<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems.

One was pointed out by @dyp in the comments section to your question. You need to use:

```
void Foo< ValA >::doSomething()
{
}
```

instead of

```
template<>
void Foo< ValA >::doSomething()
{
}
```

The other one is that you have to change the class template to:

```
template< int T >
struct Foo : virtual public Bar
{
};
```

You can't create a specialization of `Foo` using `ValA`, if you use typename as template parameter.

Comment: Why don't you use the enum as the type of the non-type template parameter?

Comment: Cool. thanks for you answer. Using the `typename` keyword was a typo. I did mean to use the enum's name instead.