# Compile error with template return type for a function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class with this declaration in the .hpp:

```
  template<class FriendClass> class SocialConnection{

    typedef std::set<FriendClass> FriendSet;
    FriendSet _socialFriends;
    public:
       virtual const FriendSet& getFriends();
```

And in the .cpp:

```
const SocialConnection::FriendSet& SocialConnection::getFriends() {
    return _socialFriends;
}
```

The compiler gives me an error for the set declaration:
`Expected a class or namespace` for the line `const SocialConnection::FriendSet& SocialConnection::getFriends()`

I have been searching why for two hours and without any result. I can't use the name of my template class in the implementation? How I can do that? Anything of syntax that I have lost?

Comment: Yes, it's included. The error is given in .cpp, if I erase the lines of the function .cpp implementation it works fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The class name in your getFriends definition is missing the template argument.
2. You can't really put your template code in a cpp file and expect it to compile. It is a template, so it is instantiated as a type wherever it is used. Therefore you will need to put it in a header.

   template < typename F>

   const typename SocialConnection< F>::FriendSet& SocialConnection< F>::getFriends() {
       return _socialFriends;
   }

Comment: "2. .. put it in a header ..." or `#include "implementation.cpp"` in the back of your header, or...

Comment: You're missing `typename` before return type.

Comment: @jrok you're right, otherwise compiler wouldn't know if FriendSet is a type or a variable name

Comment: @xtofl I do not endorse your suggestion. I have done that in the past and the build systems that I used got thoroughly confused. (you have a cpp file which you don't really want to compile which works against most assumptions.) If you really have to, you can rename it to .impl or .tpl like in some opensource projects.

Comment: @pwned: indeed; I would name the implementation file differently, too.   We have the convention to name the declaration part x.h, the implementation part x.hpp.

Answer (score 2):

The correct definition is rather long-winded:

```
template<typename FriendClass>
const typename SocialConnection<FriendClass>::FriendSet&
SocialConnection<FriendClass>::getFriends()
{
    return _socialFriends;
}
```

And what @pwned said; it needs to be visible at the point of instantiation, so put it in the header. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the) for an explanation.

Note also `typename` before the return type - it's neccessary, because `FriendSet` is a *dependent name.* [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) explains it in-depth.