# weird linker error using templates with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now.

Here's the linker error I'm getting:

```
main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::default_delete<Foo> > Bar::make_unique_pointer<Foo>()'
```

The code below demonstrates the issue I'm having.

**Bar.h**

```
class Bar {
public: 
    template <class T>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique_pointer();
};
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
#include "Bar.h"

template <class T>
std::unique_ptr<T> Bar::make_unique_pointer() {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Bar.h"

struct Foo {};

int main() {
    Bar bar;
    auto p = bar.make_unique_pointer<Foo>();  
    return 0;
}
```

However if I define the function inline, it works

```
class Bar {
public:
    template <class T>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique_pointer() {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());
    }
};
```

Or if I put the definition in `main.cpp` or even in `Bar.h` it will compile fine.

I only get the linker error when they're in separate files :/

Comment: definitely. I just wasn't searching the correct terms. voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function templates must be implemented in the same file in which they are created. [See this answer for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the).