# undefined reference to SkipNode

Tags: c++

I try to implement a skiplist and run into this error

> undefined reference to `SkipNode::SkipNode(std::string*, int)

Did I use templates incorrectly? Or do is this perhaps a linking problem?

Here is the really simple code (a scaled-down version):

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SkipNode.h"
#include "RandomHeight.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    RandomHeight rh(32, 0.5);
    string s = "Test";

    SkipNode<string> skipNode_obj(&s, rh.newLevel()); //ERROR

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        cout << rh.newLevel() << endl;
    }

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

SkipNode.h

```
#ifndef SKIPNODE_H
#define SKIPNODE_H

template<typename T>
class SkipNode
{
    public:
        SkipNode(T* value, int h);
        int getHeight();
        T* getValue();
        virtual ~SkipNode();

        SkipNode** fwdNodes;
    private:
        T* value;
        int height;
};

#endif // SKIPNODE_H
```

SkipNode.cpp

```
#include "SkipNode.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
SkipNode<T>::SkipNode(T* value, int h):value(value), height(h)
{
    fwdNodes = new SkipNode<T>* [h];
    for(int i=0; i<h; i++){
        fwdNodes[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

template<typename T>
int SkipNode<T>::getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

template<typename T>
T* SkipNode<T>::getValue()
{
    return value;
}

template<typename T>
SkipNode<T>::~SkipNode()
{
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the?lq=1. The template must\* be defined in the header and cannot be split between .h/.cpp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the definition of your class (the stuff currently in the CPP file) at the end of your header and remove the CPP file. Or alternatively, define all your methods inline.

For an explanation of why this is needed, read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the?lq=1). The short version is that you are writing a *template* for a class and not a class itself, therefore, the whole body of the template must be accessible to the compiler while it is instantiating the template per each type (or combination of types/other template parameters.)

Comment: ohhh thx...i should have known that...

it works now!

for each other, you can also use "export" template/class, but be careful it doesnt work everywhere